# Java IO outside jar

Tags: java, file, io, next-generation-plugin

I'm working on a browser based applet game, and I intend to store the top ten scores in a text file in the directory with the JAR file. How would I read and write to a text file if it's outside the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to do this is via the [JNLP persistence service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService)

Answer (score 0):

A *signed* applet (jar, JNLP) has the same disk IO permissions as the user running the applet.

Otherwise, [`javax.jnlp.PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService) is your best bet.